# SQL Server DTSWizard.exe Import and Export Wizard clr.dll Access Violation

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Earlier today I was attempting to import data in a local SQL Server instance using the built-in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard [DTSWizard.exe] which I've recently done many times. Today was not one of them. Immediately after clicking the initial 'Next' where the Source Data Sources are enumerated, DTSWizard.exe crashes immediately. Luckily, it does generate Application Events in Event Viewer.

> Application: DTSWizard.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
> The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET
> Runtime at IP 745B1AB3 (74590000) with exit code 80131506.
>
> Faulting application name: DTSWizard.exe, version: 15.0.2000.168, time
> stamp: 0x60d2af25 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4400.0,
> time stamp: 0x60b90414 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
> 0x00021ab3 Faulting process id: 0x2644 Faulting application start
> time: 0x01d798859bcd5141 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTSWizard.exe
> Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Report Id:
> f299f3ae-8e51-4bf8-a4b0-33bee2d36804 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Fault bucket 1468275927648085676, type 1 Event Name: APPCRASH
> Response: Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: DTSWizard.exe P2: 15.0.2000.168 P3: 60d2af25
> P4: clr.dll P5: 4.8.4400.0 P6: 60b90414 P7: c0000005 P8: 00021ab3 P9:
> P10:
>
> Attached files:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2CF.tmp.dmp
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF438.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF448.tmp.xml
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF446.tmp.csv
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF467.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_DTSWizard.exe_9a495bf0850f18fc52df16157df1d27143632_d6e9ae04_912b0408-c4d8-4634-820f-fde40457c5a6
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
> f299f3ae-8e51-4bf8-a4b0-33bee2d36804 Report Status: 268435456 Hashed
> bucket: 99ad5a02b5c660c124605d2d4bb8a6ac CabGuid: 0

I'm using the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio, build 15.0.18386.0, which I did reinstall but with no change. Other things which I have tried is apply all cumulative updates for .NET Framework 4.8, which brought clr.dll to file version 4.8.4400.0, timestamped 6/3/2021 1:25PM. I have also tried the .NET Framework Repair Tool which didn't seem to make a difference. Based on Windows Update, there seem to have been no recently applied hotfixes, patches, etc. between now and last week which is the time of the last successful import.

Answer (score 0):

In my expierence, this could be related to anti-virus/anti-malware software. You might need to whitelist the software.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).